# how to create short circuit on different generators with python API

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am finding it hard to create a short circuit of different generator in the IEEE 9 bus system from python.

I tried to create a short circuit on generator 1 with the code below:

the code was executed successfully but short circuit event never happened

Here is the class function:

```
def create_short_circuit(self, target_name, time,
                         duration=None, name='short circuit'):
    # get element where the  short circuit will be applied
    target = self.app.GetCalcRelevantObjects(target_name)[0]
    # get the events folder from active study case
    evt_folder = self.app.GetFromStudyCase('IntEvt')
    # create an empty event of type EvtShc (short circuit)
    evt_folder.CreateObject('EvtShc', name)
    # get the newly created event
    # sc = evt_folder.GetContents(name+'.EvtShc')[0][0]
    sc = evt_folder.GetContents(name+'.EvtShc')[0]
    # set time, target and type of short circuit (3-phase)
    sc.time = time
    sc.p_target = target
    sc.i_shc = 0
    # set clearing event if required
    if duration is not None:
        # create an empty event of type EvtShc (short circuit)
        evt_folder.CreateObject('EvtShc', name+'_clear')
        # get the newly created event
        scc = evt_folder.GetContents(
            name+'_clear'+'.EvtShc')[0]
        # set time, target and type of event (clearing)
        scc.time = time + duration
        scc.p_target = target
        scc.i_shc = 4

def delete_short_circuit(self, name='short circuit'):
    # get the events folder from active study case
    evt_folder = self.app.GetFromStudyCase('IntEvt')
    # find the short circuit and clear event to delete
    sc = evt_folder.GetContents(name+'.EvtShc')[0]
    scc = evt_folder.GetContents(name+'_clear'+'.EvtShc')[0]
    # delete short circuit and clear events if they exist
    if sc:
        sc.Delete()
    if scc:
        scc.Delete()
```

Here is the object code:

## activate project and study case

```
sim = PowerFactorySimulation(FOLDER_NAME, PROJECT_NAME, STUDY_CASE_NAME)
# get all buses in network
buses = sim.app.GetCalcRelevantObjects('*.ElmTerm')
# create result dictionaries
t = {}
f = {}
for bus in buses:
    # create short circuit on every bus
    sim.create_short_circuit(
        target_name=buses[1].loc_name+'*.ElmTerm',
        time=2.0,
        duration=0.15)
    # prepare RMS simulation
    sim.prepare_dynamic_sim(
        monitored_variables=MONITORED_VARIABLES)
    # run RMS simulation
    sim.run_dynamic_sim()
    # get and store generator response
    t[bus.loc_name], f[bus.loc_name] = \
        sim.get_dynamic_results('*.ElmSym', 's:xspeed')
    
    # delete old short circuit before new one
    sim.delete_short_circuit()
```